# How to add memory on an android phone

Tags: insufficient-memory, android-versions

I brought a sandisk memory for my android but its still saying insufficient space on device. What do I do about putting the memory on the phone?

Comment: Are you asking about ram space or sd space?  You need to provide more details.

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please take a look at [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first aid. Short hint: this error always refers to device-internal storage, no matter what big SD card you put in and how much space is free elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking about your internal memory on your phone and how to free some space.

```
What do I do about putting the memory on the phone?
```

- Move your medias such as photos, videos to your SD card with a [file
  explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)
- Move some of your [apps to SD card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.IQBS.android.app2sd&hl=en)

This process should free some space in your internal memory